# Best practice to update application-prod.yml

Tags: jenkins, war, jhipster

I want to deploy my jhipster application with Jenkins. I have developped 2 jobs one to build and generate war file and second to deploy my war file on server.
In a second one i want to update application-prod.yml in my war file because my job is use to deploy on differents environments. I use jar -uf to update my war file but the result is that my war file content only application-prod.yml after that.
I try to use shell build step with jenkins to unzip my war file but i think that is not really war file because my unzip shell command failed. Can you help me to use the best practice thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider integrating your `application-prod.yml` into your war file to be a good practice. It is usually much better to provide it as an external file.

Comment: Ok, i use this option when i start my application java -jar MyApplication.war --spring.config.location=file:\application-prod.yml but it's not ok because i choose application-prod.yml in my war file.

Comment: You should rather specify a folder than a file itself as this work if you change profile. The default search path classpath:,classpath:/config,file:,file:config/ is always used, irrespective of the value of spring.config.location. This search path is ordered from lowest to highest precedence (file:config/ wins).

Comment: So if you put `application-prod.yml` in `config` folder next to your jar/war file, it'll work without specifying `spring.config.location`. You should consider what's the use for you to have an `application-prod.yml` in your `src/main/resources`

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot, i find why spring.config.location doesn't work. My application-prod.yml is a template file, i have key / value like this :
port = @webapp_port@ 
I set port when i deploy my application with Jenkins job.
In this case the yml file is not valide, so a lot of my parameters isn't loaded !